# How to resize a group of vectors in Expression Blend/WPF/Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, expression-blend

So say for example I created a few small squares in expression blend.

I then group them together by selecting them, right clicking and selecting "Group Into -> Grid"

So now that they are in the grid, I'd like to be able to resize this grid and then they would resize but it doesn't happen, it just resizes the grid but leaves the vectors the same.

Is there a way to do what I am looking for?

p.s I know you can just select all the vectors and then resize them all, but I am looking for a way to just resize one container and not all the objects in there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same complaint.  The only work around I've found is to perform a scale transform on the grid.

It makes sense to do this when you think about how vectors work.  You don't really want to mess with the points, just mess with the size or "zoom" of the graphic.

Select the grid, go to the Properties and modify the Scale Transform values.

It will add similar xaml to your grid:

```
<Grid.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```